# request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects and server processor consumtion is 100%

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I Got this error in Apache Server

```
[Sun Mar 11 16:12:38.126941 2018] [core:error] [pid 13960] [client 45.242.206.54:37807] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://www.sarehah.ml/link.php?id=68783
```

i have added these lines to .htaccess file to prevent redirecting loop

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ link.php?id=$1 [L]
```

but the problem still exist.
what can i do ?

Comment: What are you trying achieve?

Comment: i tried to redirect each user to his specific link

Comment: You need to add a condition where it doesn't match the rewrite rule. Right now ALL requests, including the rewrite are being rewritten.

Comment: so , what can i do @Rick

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, right now ALL your hits are being rewritten, you need to exclude the one you want to pass through

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/link.php?id=*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ link.php?id=$1 [L]
```